# Change Color of DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I wanted to change the color of the entire row but `row is null` with my current code. `datagrid.Rows` doesn't exist.

I want to highlight the 3<sup>rd</sup> row for example.

```
var row = datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(3) as Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow;
row.Background = Brushes.Blue;
```

Comment: That's WPF, isn't it?

Comment: yes, it is.......

Comment: Does the background color depend on a property or something else? You could try it with using styles.

Comment: It's Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid

Comment: Yes it depends. Instead of that 3 it has a function and changes this value depending on a timer

Comment: How to fill grid?

Comment: Are you using the MVVM pattern? You could set a property of the ViewModel which represents one row and use a style to change the background of this row.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
          <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Executed}" Value="False">
                      <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCoral" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Executed}" Value="True">
                      <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>     
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

In this case I am using caliburn micro to bind the background color depending on a bool within my row (used bool? to remain white until bool is changed).

Comment: and how do I trigger the color change? In the code.

Comment: By setting the bool to either false or true.
`private bool _executed;
    public bool Executed
    {
      get => _executed;
      set
      {
        _executed = value;

        NotifyOfPropertyChange();
      }
    `
This is how you do it from the viewmodel using caliburn micro. Setting the executed will update the view

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the best way to change the background of a `DataGridRow` - you should use a `Style` as suggested by @David Danielewicz - but for your current approach to work you should cast the object returned from the method to a **System**.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow.

You should also use the `ContainerFromIndex` method to get a reference to the visual container for the fourth element. The third element has an index of 2.

Try this:

```
var row = datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(2) as System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow;
row.Background = Brushes.Blue;
```

Also note that for this to work, you need to wait until the containers have actually been created:

```
datagrid.Loaded += (ss, ee) => 
{
    var row = datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(2) as System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow;
    row.Background = Brushes.Blue;
};
```

Comment: same thing. row = null

Comment: Where do you actually execute this code? You must wait until the containers have actually been created.

Comment: Well, it says it's null but the code doesnt crash. If I check `steps.ItemContainerGenerator` I can see all the items. So i'm pretty sure it's getting the data from the table.

Comment: Try to call the ContainerFromIndex in a Loaded event handler as per my edit and please provide a full sample of your issue if you still cannot get it working: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Accessing View from code behind is a bad practice. Better use the power of MVVM:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle" TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RowBackground}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Records}" RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">        
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>    
</Window>

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(); 
}

public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Records.Add(new RecordViewModel()
        {
            Value = "Red",
            RowBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightCoral)
        });

        Records.Add(new RecordViewModel()
        {
            Value = "Green",
            RowBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen)
        });

        Records.Add(new RecordViewModel()
        {
            Value = "Blue",
            RowBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue)
        });

        Records[2].Value = "Not blue anymore";
        Records[2].RowBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightPink);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<RecordViewModel> Records { get; } = new ObservableCollection<RecordViewModel>();
}

public class RecordViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _value;
    private Brush _rowBG;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
        }
    }

    public Brush RowBackground
    {
        get
        {
            return _rowBG;
        }
        set
        {
            _rowBG = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RowBackground));
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```